# Domain class not accessible in my controller

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I'm new to Grails and groovy..
I created a domain class

```
\grails-app\domain\Abc
```

Now i created a controller in

```
\grails-app\controllers\myapp\myController
```

In that, when i created an object it shows error.

```
def Abc obj = new Abc
```

The error i got is

```
unable to resolve class Abc
```

I tried to import, but didn't shown there also. Me working in grails 1.3.7 and IntelliJ IDEA 10.0.2
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the location of each class is consistent with the class and package declaration.

> I created a domain class
>
> \grails-app\domain\Abc

This class should look like this

```
class Abc {
    // implementation omitted
}
```

make sure you have no package declaration, because based on the location, this class should be in the default package (which is actually a bad practice). Ideally you should put this class into a package, then move the source file into a subdirectory of `\grails-app\domain` that corresponds to the package name.

> Now i created a controller in
>
> \grails-app\controllers\myapp\myController

This class should look like this

```
package myapp
  
class myController {
    // implementation omitted
}
```

Notice that this class should be named with a lower-case 'm' because that's how the file is named. The standard Java/Groovy naming conventions dictate that classes should begin with a capital letter.

> In that, when i created an object it shows error.

```
def Abc obj = new Abc
```

There are a couple of problems with this code:

- define the type as either `def` or
  `Abc` but not both
- you're missing some parentheses

Try this instead:

```
Abc obj = new Abc()
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you created your domain class & controller class manually. First, your controller should be in the folder `controllers`, not `myapp`. Second, you should define a package for both your domain class & controller class, for example:

Domain class:

```
package myapp

class Book {
...
}
```

Controller class

```
package myapp

class BookController {
....
}
```

Comment: If his controller is already in a packaged named myapp then it's in the correct folder

Comment: @Don: I think it's best to simplify as much as possible; and give a working example. If the controller in myapp folder, the domain class should be in domain/myapp too.

Comment: Thanks for you answer... the problem was with package